# Not able to traverse elements in Binary search tree in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal, inorder

I am trying to print all the elements using inorder traversal, but my code is giving incorrect output. I am not able to figure out what went wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node * left;
    struct node * right;
};

class Btree
{
    node * root;

    void insert(int value, node * leaf);
    node * search(int value, node * leaf);
    void destroy(node * leaf);


    public:
        Btree() { root = NULL; }
        ~Btree() {  destroy();  }
        void insert(int value);
        node * search(int value);
        void destroy();
        void inorder(node * ptr);
};

void Btree::inorder(node *ptr)
{
    if (ptr != NULL)
    {
        inorder(ptr->left);
        cout << ptr->value << "";
        inorder(ptr->right);
    }
}

void Btree::destroy(node *leaf)
{
    if(leaf!=NULL)
    {
            destroy(leaf->left);
            destroy(leaf->right);
            delete leaf;
    }
}

void Btree :: destroy()
{
    destroy(root);
}


node *Btree::search(int value, node *leaf)
{
    if(leaf!=NULL)
    {   
            if(value==leaf->value)
            return leaf;
            if(value<leaf->value)
            return search(value, leaf->left);
            else 
        return search(value, leaf->right);
    }
    else return NULL;
}

node *Btree::search(int value)
{
    return search(value, root);
}


void Btree::insert(int value, node *leaf)
{
    if(value< leaf->value)
    {
           if(leaf->left!=NULL)
            insert(value, leaf->left);
           else
           {
            leaf->left=new node;
            leaf->left->value=value;
            leaf->left->left=NULL;    //Sets the left child of the child node to null
            leaf->left->right=NULL;   //Sets the right child of the child node to null
           }  
    }
    else if(value>=leaf->value)
    {
           if(leaf->right!=NULL)
            insert(value, leaf->right);
           else
           {
            leaf->right=new node;
            leaf->right->value=value;
            leaf->right->left=NULL;  //Sets the left child of the child node to null
            leaf->right->right=NULL; //Sets the right child of the child node to null
           }
    }   
}


void Btree::insert(int value)
{
  if(root!=NULL)
        insert(value, root);
  else
  {
        root=new node;
        root->value=value;
        root->left=NULL;
        root->right=NULL;
  }
}


int main()
{
    Btree bst;
    struct node * root = NULL;
    root = new node;
    bst.insert(10);
    bst.insert(6);
    bst.insert(14);
    bst.insert(3);
    bst.insert(8);
    bst.insert(7);
    bst.insert(9);
    bst.insert(5);

    bst.inorder(root);
    return 1;
}
```

I have tried to create a memory pointer that is the root and then passing that root in my inorder function call. My inorder should print me the output

```
3 5 6 7 8 9 10 14
```

A pointer to a step-debugger would help me in solving the issue I believe.Or if anyone can provide me the corrected code, would be quite helpful

Edit:- I had previously passed ptr but used root in my inorder function definition (due to which I was getting Bus error), but now it is correected. However, I still do not get the right output. The output I get is `0`

Comment: [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) is a debugger that will help you.

Comment: Your `inorder` function takes an argument you ignore, and instead use the member variable root, every time. This function is infinitely recursive because of that and eventually you get a stack overflow.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I did not get you. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Look carefully at your inorder function. You pass a parameter, but ignore it. The code checks if the root member variable is not null then calls the inorder function recursively with root->left. The parameter is ignored and the function calls itself with root->left as a parameter that is ignored, repeat this forever.

Comment: @RetiredNinja My bad, I just corrected it in the question, but still I am not able to print expected output.

Comment: That's because the root pointer you want to use is the member variable in your Btree class, not the completely unrelated one you created in main.  https://ideone.com/oizPS3

Comment: @RetiredNinja solved!  used a new function to return the class variable root and assigned it to newly created in main ptr and passed ptr as argument. Thanks.